# C : how can I change from file descriptor to FILE struct and vice versa?

Tags: c, linux

Is there any way to change an `int` file descriptor to a `FILE` struct pointer or/and change `FILE*` to a file descriptor in C?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The function `fdopen()` returns a new (FILE *) associated with an open file descriptor.

The function `fileno()` returns the file descriptor associated with an open FILE *.

Comment: Caveat: `fdopen` takes ownership, whereas `fileno` returns a view. It is very difficult to avoid some of the edge cases even if you use `dup` in conjunction, since `fclose` modifies the underlying file descriptor.

Answer (score 28):

Use "[fileno()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fileno.html)" for FILE->int.

Use "[fdopen()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fdopen.html)" for int->FILE.